# x = {} creates spontaneous object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Part of a larger program using AngularJs, the code fragment:

```
var thePortList = $scope.ipPortList; // an array of objects
...
...
console.log("before", $scope.ipPortList, thePortList);
thePortList[i] = {};
console.log("after", $scope.ipPortList, thePortList);
```

Creates this output:

```
before [] []
after [2: Object] [2: Object]
```

I have no idea why.  I could expect to see something like this in a multi-threaded program but not in Javascript.

x = {} should assign a new, empty object to that element in the array. Right?  I am baffled about this behavior.  Can anyone shed some light?

Tested in Chrome on both my local machine and plunkr.

Plunkr here:

Complete plunkr console output: [Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/nzcDIv1h6kSzhkmCEjQH?p=preview)

```
Event tracked Multipane Show Preview Toolbar undefined undefined
editor-0.11.1.js:2 URL visited /?p=preview
VM631:29 portList []
VM631:34 processing 0 [] undefined
VM631:39 skipping 0
VM631:34 processing 1 [] undefined
VM631:39 skipping 1
VM631:34 processing 2 [] undefined
VM631:45 before [] []
VM631:47 after [2: Object] [2: Object]
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Is the problem that the object is appearing in *both* of `$scope.ipPortList` and `thePortList`? Because that is correct behaviour given that both refer to the same array.

Comment: Can you tell us what was your expected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a correct behavior, I think you misunderstand the meaning of log info.
You can try this code in console, and see the result:

```
var a=[];
a[2]={};
a

output: [undefined × 2, Object__proto__: Object]
```

The console log info '[2: Object]' omitted 2 undefined, in JavaScript if you assign a value to an array item which out of his length, you will get undefined if try to access the element from origin length to the index, and it's not because the array auto fill undefined, because this is the standard response to accessing a non existent property. In reality nothing has changed except the array length.

Comment: *" if you assign a value to an array item which out of his length, undefined will automatically completed until the item index"* - JS doesn't create elements with the value `undefined` to fill the gap. That is, there is a difference between a missing element that has never had a value and an element that has explictly been assigned the value `undefined`. (But the console does let you know how many elements are missing.)

Comment: @nnnnnn an interesting proof of this is that `Array(2).forEach(i => console.log(i))` and `[undefined, undefined].forEach(i => console.log(i))` produce different outputs. One is an empty array whose length has been set to 2, the other is an array with 2 actual undefined's in it

Comment: @MatisLepik - even the way Chrome logs those example arrays in the console is different.